# How to render common header and footer in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux, native-base

**I want to add header and footer in all pages like below.**

**write code once then how render it in various pages?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one at the bottom is called `TabNavigator`, and the one above is called `StackNavigator`. Once you declare a navigator as one of them, that navigator can be accessed from anywhere and be shown everywhere. Both can be found and imported from `react-navigation'.